# How to Run PHP coding dynamically

Tags: php, html, apache

I want to type php coding in textarea, then after submit it should run the php coding and produce result. Is this possible ?

To upload changes in live, I need to get two level approve, If any errors occur i could't fix it quickly, If above thing is possible I can enable error log, dynamically print array and so on...

Comment: You are asking a lot of things. What have you tried? What do you mean by "two level approve"? What do you mean by "and so on..."? You need to be clearer in your question, and show us your existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can `POST` value of `textarea` and then evaluate its content as PHP code using [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but make sure you restrict access to this feature, because it's very dangerous if you allow random people to use it. You can even simulate something like online php compiler using AJAX calls.